# Transform from timestamped records to 15 minute periodic records

Tags: sql, oracle, time-series

I have records that relate to the location of an RFID tagged asset within a building. The records have start and end timestamps and the location where the asset was between those 2 timestamps.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ZONEID</td>
    <td>MACADDRESS</td>
    <td>START_TS</td>
    <td>END_TS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SJC20-3-NZ-4</td>
    <td>00:00:04:be:23:7c</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:00:30.000000000 AM</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:04:26.000000000 AM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SJC20-3-NZ-4</td>
    <td>00:00:04:be:23:7c</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:04:26.000000000 AM</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:04:28.000000000 AM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SJC20-3-NZ-5</td>
    <td>00:00:04:be:23:7c</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:04:28.000000000 AM</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:14:49.000000000 AM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SJC20-3-NZ-5</td>
    <td>00:00:04:be:23:7c</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:14:49.000000000 AM</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:15:08.000000000 AM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SJC20-3-NZ-5</td>
    <td>00:00:04:be:23:7c</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:15:08.000000000 AM</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:16:49.000000000 AM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SJC20-3-NZ-6</td>
    <td>00:00:04:be:23:7c</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:16:49.000000000 AM</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:17:17.000000000 AM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SJC20-3-NZ-6</td>
    <td>00:00:04:be:23:7c</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:17:17.000000000 AM</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:19:09.000000000 AM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SJC20-3-NZ-6</td>
    <td>00:00:04:be:23:7c</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:19:09.000000000 AM</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:19:22.000000000 AM</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to transform this so for every 15 minute interval in a day I can say how many minutes each asset spent in each location it was detected. Like follows, I need to do this in Oracle SQL.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ZONEID</td>
    <td>MACADDRESS</td>
    <td>START_TS</td>
    <td>END_TS</td>
    <td>TIME_MINS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SJC20-3-NZ-4</td>
    <td>00:00:04:be:23:7c</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:00:00.000000000 AM</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:15:00.000000000 AM</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SJC20-3-NZ-5</td>
    <td>00:00:04:be:23:7c</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:00:00.000000000 AM</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:15:00.000000000 AM</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SJC20-3-NZ-5</td>
    <td>00:00:04:be:23:7c</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:15:00.000000000 AM</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:30:00.000000000 AM</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SJC20-3-NZ-6</td>
    <td>00:00:04:be:23:7c</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:15:00.000000000 AM</td>
    <td>13/10/20 07:30:00.000000000 AM</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What about session `13/10/20 07:14:49` to `13/10/20 07:15:08`? Does it count for interval `2020-10-13 07:00:00 - 07:15:00` or in `2020-10-13 07:15:00 - 07:30:00`? I.e. is the start time or the end time relevant (or both)?

Answer (score 0):

I use this general function for such problem:

```
FUNCTION MakeInterval(ts IN TIMESTAMP, roundInterval IN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND) RETURN TIMESTAMP DETERMINISTIC IS
    denom INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' HOUR THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(HOUR FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(24, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts) + TRUNC(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' HOUR;
    ELSIF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' MINUTE THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'hh') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE;
    ELSE
        denom := EXTRACT(SECOND FROM roundInterval);                
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'mi') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' SECOND;
    END IF;
END MakeInterval;
```

Then the query would be like this:

```
select COUNT(*),
    ZONEID, MACADDRESS, 
    MakeInterval(START_TS, INTERVAL '15' MINUTES) as START_TS,
    MakeInterval(START_TS, INTERVAL '15' MINUTES) + INTERVAL '15' MINUTES as END_TS
from t
GROUP BY MakeInterval(START_TS, INTERVAL '15' MINUTES);
```

Comment: The OP wants the sum of the number of minutes within each 15 minute interval and each row could be within multiple intervals (there is a `SJC20-3-NZ-5` row that goes from `07:14:49` to `07:15:08`).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the minimum and maximum time bounds (to the nearest preceding 15 minute interval) and then use a row generator to generate 15 minute intervals between those bounds and then use a partitioned outer join (or `INNER JOIN` if you don't want the rows containing 0 time) and sum the minutes within the interval:

```sql
WITH bounds ( min_ts, max_ts ) AS (
  SELECT TRUNC( MIN( start_ts ), 'HH' )
         + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE
           * TRUNC(
               (
                 TRUNC( MIN( start_ts ), 'MI' ) - TRUNC( MIN( start_ts ), 'HH' )
               ) * 24 * 4
             ),
         TRUNC( MAX( end_ts ), 'HH' )
         + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE
           * TRUNC(
               (
                 TRUNC( MAX( end_ts ), 'MI' ) - TRUNC( MAX( end_ts ), 'HH' )
               ) * 24 * 4
             )
  FROM   table_name
),
interval_times ( ts ) AS (
  SELECT min_ts + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * INTERVAL '15' MINUTE AS ts
  FROM   bounds
  CONNECT BY min_ts + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * INTERVAL '15' MINUTE <= max_ts
)
SELECT t.zoneid,
       t.macaddress,
       i.ts AS start_ts,
       i.ts + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE AS end_ts,
       SUM(
         COALESCE(
           (
             LEAST( i.ts + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE, t.end_ts )
             - GREATEST( i.ts, t.start_ts )
           ) * 24 * 60,
           0
         )
       ) AS time_mins
FROM   interval_times i
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
       PARTITION BY ( t.zoneid, t.macaddress )
       ON ( t.start_ts < i.ts + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE AND i.ts < t.end_ts )
GROUP BY
       t.zoneid,
       t.macaddress,
       i.ts
ORDER BY
       i.ts,
       t.macaddress,
       t.zoneid;
```

Which for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ZONEID, MACADDRESS, START_TS, END_TS ) AS
SELECT 'SJC20-3-NZ-4', '00:00:04:be:23:7c', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 07:00:30', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 07:04:26' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SJC20-3-NZ-4', '00:00:04:be:23:7c', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 07:04:26', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 07:04:28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SJC20-3-NZ-5', '00:00:04:be:23:7c', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 07:04:28', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 07:14:49' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SJC20-3-NZ-5', '00:00:04:be:23:7c', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 07:14:49', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 07:15:08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SJC20-3-NZ-5', '00:00:04:be:23:7c', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 07:15:08', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 07:16:49' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SJC20-3-NZ-6', '00:00:04:be:23:7c', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 07:16:49', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 07:17:17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SJC20-3-NZ-6', '00:00:04:be:23:7c', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 07:17:17', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 07:19:09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SJC20-3-NZ-6', '00:00:04:be:23:7c', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 07:19:09', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 07:19:22' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ZONEID       | MACADDRESS        | START_TS            | END_TS              |                                 TIME_MINS
> :----------- | :---------------- | :------------------ | :------------------ | ----------------------------------------:
> SJC20-3-NZ-4 | 00:00:04:be:23:7c | 2020-01-13 07:00:00 | 2020-01-13 07:15:00 |  3.96666666666666666666666666666666666666
> SJC20-3-NZ-5 | 00:00:04:be:23:7c | 2020-01-13 07:00:00 | 2020-01-13 07:15:00 | 10.53333333333333333333333333333333333333
> SJC20-3-NZ-6 | 00:00:04:be:23:7c | 2020-01-13 07:00:00 | 2020-01-13 07:15:00 |                                         0
> SJC20-3-NZ-4 | 00:00:04:be:23:7c | 2020-01-13 07:15:00 | 2020-01-13 07:30:00 |                                         0
> SJC20-3-NZ-5 | 00:00:04:be:23:7c | 2020-01-13 07:15:00 | 2020-01-13 07:30:00 |  1.81666666666666666666666666666666666666
> SJC20-3-NZ-6 | 00:00:04:be:23:7c | 2020-01-13 07:15:00 | 2020-01-13 07:30:00 |  2.55000000000000000000000000000000000001
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9f335f8d94adaca06430e2e8408f4f82)*